# How to scrape location data from an online leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, leaflet

I want to access the locations used for the markers in this site https://newspapermap.com, but i can't find the HTML tag that contains it when I inspect the map. It's a leaflet map, made with JS, but I don't know how to reverse engineering to put it like that.

Any guidance would be great.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is loaded from `https://pap.as/api/index.php/records/newspapermap?include=lat,lng,n,u,l` and then stored in the browser's `localStorage`.

If you clear your browser's `localStorage` for that page manually, you'll see the URL in the network inspector.

Comment: Found the entire .json there! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The location is inside the `leaflet-popup  leaflet-zoom-animated` `div` class, in a `h3` tag.

Use the search function and search `leaflet-popup  leaflet-zoom-animated` when inspecting the element.

To grab them all, i would select all instances of `leaflet-popup  leaflet-zoom-animated` using for example a css selector, then iterate over them to extract all of the `h3` tags in to a list.

P.S. Make sure you are using Selenium or another library that can deal with dynamic websites.

Comment: That combo led me to the popup, but the content only has the name for the newspaper inside h3, the coordinates aren't printed but sometimes they show in the adress bar.

Comment: @TwoPointNo That's strange, it should be giving the location. Try to work down the hierarchy. So within `leaflet-popup  leaflet-zoom-animated` try to extract `leaflet-popup-content` and *then* take the `h3` tags.

Once you have the location names you can use a geolocator library such as geopy in Python to use the city name to retrieve the coordinates.

Comment: Great idea, it was just an attempt to skip that extra step and because I could see it has the coordinates down to the office adress level, which would be cool.